# Perform HTTP Posts in a row Obj C

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, http, post

I want to get a linked .csv file, that is available after posting to a http form.
The URL (in code it's kURL) is http://www2.htw-dresden.de/~rawa/cgi-bin/auf/raiplan_kal.php.
I try to get the result with:

```
NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"unix=%@&pressme=%@",_password,@"S+T+A+R+T"];

    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:kURL
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:10];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    [request setValue:@"4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"w1"];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (connectionError) NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [connectionError localizedDescription]);
        else {
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
        }
    }];
```

As result I get:

```
...
<form name=Testform method=post action=../plan/t21.csv><INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=w1 value=4></form><script type="text/javascript">
function AbGehts() {document.Testform.submit();}
window.setTimeout("AbGehts()",1);
</script>
...
```

I need the file that is created after the javascript-function AbGehts(). But how can I get this?

I hope you can help me without the password that is needed in this form, I can't publish this..

Comment: So you don't have a proper web service to call? And you can't add one? And you can't encode whatever redirection the javascript does into the app?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. The web service I call is a service run at my university. I want the data that is behind the hidden form after my first request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That button just makes a POST request to http://www2.htw-dresden.de/~rawa/cgi-bin/plan/t21.csv

Testing in a browser, it also works with a GET.  If you use that URL, you will be able to get the CSV data directly.

EDIT:

To get the filename dynamically a regex like this would work:

```
NSString *html = @"<form name=Testform method=post action=../plan/t21.csv>";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<form name=Testform method=post action=\\.\\.\\/plan\\/([^>]*)>" options:0 error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regex firstMatchInString:html options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, html.length)];
if(result) {
    NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *filename = [html substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(@"filename: %@", filename);
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I edited the code. The first one was a test if this works. But die file does not everytime is named t21.csv. It could also be t20.csv or something else.

Comment: In that case you could use a regex to get the filename and build the URL dynamically. Editing the answer...

Comment: Thanks! That was not exactly what I was expecting, but it works perfectly, thank you!